# What's the best of live-calling quil functions?

Tags: clojure, quil, livecoding

I use Emacs+CIDER. I like to be able to do something akin to just evaling `(quil/frame-rate 90)`. But Calling that function is only possible within a sketch function. So I have added a `live-calls` function in which I put these kinds of code, and I call `live-calls` at the start of the draw function. Which is a very ugly hack. What's the idiomatic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by searching in closed issues in github:

```
(quil.applet/with-applet sketch-name
  (q/frame-rate 3))
```